# how can i use two javascript slideshows on one page? html

Tags: javascript, html, css, computer-science

Hi I am doing HTML the past 3 months in college and have to design a website.  I am nearly done but I am trying to put 4 slideshows onto one page.  I can get one working fine but the next one i create seems to overwrite the first one.. could somebody please look at my code and give me an idea what i should do.. here is my code for both slideshows except links and images are diferent.

```js
var i = 0; 
  var image = new Array();   
  // LIST OF IMAGES 
  image[0] = "strawberrypancakes.jpg" 
  image[1] = "chickenbroth.jpg"; 
  image[2] = "noodlesalad.jpg";   
  var k = image.length-1;    

  var caption = new Array(); 
  // LIST OF CAPTIONS 
  caption[0] = "Strawberry buckwheat pancakes"; 
  caption[1] = "Hot chicken broth"; 
  caption[2] = "Pepper and noodle salad"; 

  var link= new Array();   
  // LIST OF LINKS 
  link[0] = "http://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/breakfast/"; 
  link[1] = "http://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/chicken/"; 
  link[2] = "http://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/vegetables/";   
         

  function swapImage(){ 
  var el = document.getElementById("mydiv"); 
  el.innerHTML=caption[i]; 
  var img = document.getElementById("slide"); 
  img.src= image[i]; 
  var a = document.getElementById("link"); 
  a.href= link[i]; 

  if(i < k ) { i++;}  
  else  { i = 0; } 
                setTimeout("swapImage()",5000); 
     } 
  function addLoadEvent(func) { 
  var oldonload = window.onload; 
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') { 
  window.onload = func; 
  } else  { 
  window.onload = function() { 
  if (oldonload) { 
  oldonload(); 
  } 
  func(); 
  } 
  }
  } 
  addLoadEvent(function() { 
  swapImage(); 
  });
```

```html
  <table style="border:none;background-color:transparent;"> 
  <tr> 
         <td> 
         <a name="link" id="link" href="http://www.siteforinfotech.com/"       target="_blank"><img name="slide" id="slide" alt 

 ="my images" height="250" width="590" src="image-1.png"/></a> 
  </td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
  <td align="center"style="font:small-caps bold 15px georgia; color:blue;"> 
  <div id ="mydiv"></div>
  </td> 
  </tr>  
  </table>
```

Comment: You are probably using the same ID for both. Try using different Id's or referencing both by class

Comment: Seems like the way `window.onload` is called can be an issue; also you might need to use `setInterval` not `setTimeout`. It would be great if you could elaborate on what you mean by *I am trying to put 4 slideshows onto one page*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest thing, off the top of my head is to just duplicate the HTML structure for the slideshow, changing the ID and NAME attributes to link2, slide2 and mydiv2, then just duplicate the swap function, name it swapImage2() and then add it like so:

```
addLoadEvent(function() {
    swapImage();   // for the first slideshow
    swapImage2();  // for second slideshow
});
```

a cleaner solution would be to have a single swapimage function and pass into it the target DOM element / slideshow you want to target.

heres a quick fiddle of the quickest way I could think of [Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/r4mLdz8p/2/)